# Visual Basic 2010 Express - Adding Items to the ListView

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to know how to simply add items to the ListView while moving them down the index. I am trying to add three items; one item to each column. The ListView consists of three columns (Date, Description, Length). I want the user to be able to add text using a TextBox that will then add the date to the first column using the "Now" property, add the TextBox's text to the Description column, and then have the third column count the descriptions length using the "Length" property.

It sounds rather complicated, but I am sure the answer may just be over-looked.

Comment: Windows Forms Application

Comment: Sorry just noticed that you needed vb.net

Comment: Do you mean placing the new one at the top?

Comment: no, just adding a new entry without it replacing the previous one. Every time I wanted to add a new entry, it would just cover the previous one leaving me with just one entry.

Comment: below should work, its working on my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the datetime how you would like. Just put that in your onclick event for your button, If that is what you are using.

c#:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty) return;
    listView1.Items.AddRange( new[]
    {
        new ListViewItem(DateTime.Now.ToString()) , 
        new ListViewItem(textBox1.Text) , 
        new ListViewItem(textBox1.Text.Length.ToString())
    } );
    textBox1.Clear();
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)             
    If textBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
        Return
    End If
    listView1.Items.AddRange(New () {New ListViewItem(DateTime.Now.ToString()), New ListViewItem(textBox1.Text), New ListViewItem(textBox1.Text.Length.ToString())})
End Sub
```