# Get Text From a ListView SubItem

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an application for windows desktop using Visual Basic 2010 Express. The program I am designing has three main controls: a ListView, a TextBox, and a Button. What I need is when the user clicks a row inside of the ListView control, the TextBox will show the text within the first SubItem. To elaborate, the ListView control has two columns (Name and Description). In the SelectedIndexChanged event, I need code that will display the Description text in the TextBox (the ListView SubItem).

I would post my code to show what I have done, but I do not know where to even start, for all my code has just given me errors. I tried something like this:

```
textbox1.text = listview1.items.subitems.tostring
```

But obviously this method is useless and completely off track. I know this is basic, but I do not understand it. Thanks

Comment: how is this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20027133/1070452 from moments ago inadequate?

Comment: It is inadequate because it is not the same question. I'm not adding anything to the listview this time. I'm simply getting text from the subitem and putting it inside a textbox.

Comment: You get an error with that code: "Error 'subitems' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the item and subItem on the ListViewControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918918/how-to-get-the-item-and-subitem-on-the-listviewcontrol)

Comment: No where near the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for the text of the selected LV Item:

```
 textbox1.text = listview1.SelectedItem.ToString
```

For the text of SubItem N of the First selected Item:

```
  textbox1.text = listview1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(N).Text
```

you can also get it using  `listview1.Items(X).SubItems(N).Text` where X is the index of the Item (row) you want

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the subitem you clicked on from a listview control simply use ListViewHitTestInfo in a mouse click event i.e

```
 Dim info As ListViewHitTestInfo = lstvw1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
 MsgBox(info.SubItem.Text)
```