# Getting the text of a listview subitem

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to get the text of a ListView subitem in vb.net. according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134019/6207504) answer, the below code should work.

```
Function gen() As String
    Dim Log = New Logging.Log("gen")
    Dim Code As String = getTemplateCode()
    For Each i As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        Log.WriteEntry("Item: " + i.Text)
        If i.SubItems.Count > 0 Then
            Log.WriteEntry("Item: " + i.SubItems(0).Text)
            Code = Code.Replace(i.Text, i.SubItems(0).Text)
        End If
    Next
    Return Code
End Function
```

However, instead of getting string in `ListViewItem.SubItem.Text`, i am getting what seems to be the `ListViewItem.Text`, and cant figure out why.

Here's the actual log output from the above code:

```
gen Information: 0 : Item: $Parshah$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $Parshah$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $Year$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $Year$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $EnglishId$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $EnglishId$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $books$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $books$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $title$
gen Information: 0 : Item: $title$
```

and a screenshot of the listview

[image: Listview_Screenshot_Sample]

The log output should've been

```
gen Information: 0 : Item: $Parshah$
gen Information: 0 : Item: nothing
gen Information: 0 : Item: $Year$
gen Information: 0 : Item: nothing
gen Information: 0 : Item: $EnglishId$
gen Information: 0 : Item: nothing
gen Information: 0 : Item: $books$
gen Information: 0 : Item: nothing
gen Information: 0 : Item: $title$
gen Information: 0 : Item: nothing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Stupid mistake. A drop of research told me that a ListViewItem contains itself in its first subitem, and the first dynamically added subitem starts with an index of one instead of zero. (oops.)
Think Batch Arguments where %~0 is the file itself... lol.

SO, we change the code like this:

```
    Function gen() As String
        Dim Log = New Logging.Log("gen")
        Dim Code As String = getTemplateCode()
        For Each i As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            Log.WriteEntry("Item: " + i.Text)
            If i.SubItems.Count > 0 Then
                Log.WriteEntry("Item: " + i.SubItems(1).Text) 'changed 0 to 1
                Code = Code.Replace(i.Text, i.SubItems(1).Text) 'changed 0 to 1
            End If
        Next
        Return Code
    End Function
```